# Problems while applying a method to an stream of floating numbers array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, floating-point

I have the following `Predictor` class, which implements a `predict()` method:

```
class Predictor {

    public static int predict(double[] atts) {
        if (atts.length != 3) {
            return -1;
        }
        int i, j;

        ;

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            double sum = 0.;
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                sum += Math.log(2. * Math.PI * sigmas[i][j]);
            }
            double nij = -0.5 * sum;
            sum = 0.;
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                sum += Math.pow(atts[j] - thetas[i][j], 2.) / sigmas[i][j];
            }
            nij -= 0.5 * sum;
            likelihoods[i] = Math.log(priors[i]) + nij;
        }

        double highestLikeli = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        int classIndex = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (likelihoods[i] > highestLikeli) {
                highestLikeli = likelihoods[i];
                classIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return classIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 3) {
            double[] atts = new double[args.length];
            for (int i = 0, l = args.length; i < l; i++) {
                atts[i] = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(Predictor.predict(atts));
        }
    }
}
```

The predict method predicts a number label (i.e. int number `0` or `1`). Which I am using inside an android app in order to given an array of floats `predict` the number label of such array of floats. Visually, this looks as follows:

```
arrayOfFloats -> predict_method -> Label(0/1)
```

Note that, arrayOfFloats is a stream of data (consecutively I will have several of this arrays).

Here is the code:

```
public void run() { //stuff that updates ui
    finalValues = String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", rollValue, pitchValue, yawValue, gxValue, gyValue, gzValue);
    //finalValues = String.format("%s, %s, %s\n",  rollValue, pitchValue, yawValue);

    Log.e("WalkingActivity", finalValues);

    WalkingLog.setText(finalValues);

    // Classifier
    values[0] = rollValue;
    values[1] = pitchValue;
    values[2] = yawValue;
    //values[3] = gxValue;
    //values[4] = gyValue;
    //values[5] = gzValue;

    int y_pred = Brain.predict(values);

    ClassifierLog.setText(Integer.toString(y_pred));

    System.out.println("pred: " + Integer.toString(y_pred));

    int counter = 0;

    //Simple threshold
    if (rollValue < -40 && rollValue > -80
      && pitchValue < 0 && yawValue > 0
      && gxValue < 1000 && gxValue > -2000
      && gyValue < 500 && gyValue > -1000
      && gzValue < 1000 && gzValue > -2000) {
        ClassifierLog.setText("N");                                                 
        System.out.println("COUNTER: " + counter);

    } else {
        counter++;                                         
        ClassifierLog.setText("W");                                               
        System.out.println("COUNTER: " + counter);
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that I am always getting the same number label `1` (I am predicting the same number) instead of getting a different output `0` or `1`. As far I understand I need to append all the float values in a single array. Although I try to pass such array to the predict method it is not working. However it is not working, which is the correct way to use the `predict` method from the `Predictor` class?,

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do or what you're asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: What the predictor is supposed to predict, for starters.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to return 0 or 1. And where does `atts` come in to the picture?

Comment: @shmosel `atts` is the input (array of floats) which `predict` uses to infer the number label (0 or 1). Note that the array of floats is sensor data, so its going to be changing, furthermore, its going to be a stream, thus I have a lot of this little arrays of floats.

Comment: I asked a simple question and you're not giving me a straight answer. The fact that `predict()` returns 0 or 1 tells me **nothing** about what the method is supposed to do. And the fact that `atts` is sensor data tells me **nothing** about what it represents or how it relates to the `predict()` method.

Comment: ok, predict is a machine learning algorithm which given an array, predicts its class (0 or 1). If you check the second code (where is where I call predict it receives accelerometer and gyroscope data) @shmosel is it more clear? The method is suposed to detect if someone is walking or not.

Comment: Since I can't see where you're initializing the `values` array, I assume it's shared. If you start multiple Threads to calculate the prediction which are all sharing the values array, you might get mixed values. Of course the easiest question to ask is: Is your algorithm working?

Comment: @damian, thanks for the help. The algorithm is working, actually is from [sklearnporter](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter)

Comment: Did you try the implementation with some default input and it produced the expected values?

Comment: yes, the prediction change.

Comment: Did you try initializing the `values` array in the `Runnable` / `Thread`? I don't see the initialization, as mentioned before, which leads me to believe it's shared between the calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the help @damian, how can I do that?

Comment: It would help you to get an answer if you could supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It seems that your question is about Java but you may be looking other assistance. It's not clear.

Comment: Yeah... the thing is that the project is very large.... these are the significant parts of the code. @Cheticamp. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the initialization for priors, thetas and sigmas arrays? or how are they calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to obtain a solution is to construct & present a very small java class that runs and only contains the bare essentials of the issue you wish to have solved (including the inputs). While it will take you a small amount of effort to do this, it will clearly convey what you are attempting to accomplish.  *See my example below.*

My best guess is that you are simply looking to pass in an array of three values and return a single result.  If that is the case, then your first code example shows that you are already doing that correctly.

Thus, your issue of always returning 1 is in the logic of the Predictor code itself; i.e. the sigma/theta logic (which you have not conveyed their values).  However, knowing you are passing the values in/out correctly, means you simply need to debug the sigma/theta logic.  For example, after the if statement in the highestLikeli loop, add a sysout:

```
    System.out.format("%d %f %f\n",classIndex,highestLikeli,likelihoods[i]);
```

For reference, here's a small java file showing the array values being passed in and the predictor value being passed out (which is what your question seems to be about).

```
    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String params[][] = { { "3.3", "4.4", "5.5" }, { "5.5", "3.3", "4.4" }, { "4.4", "5.5", "3.3" } };
            for (int i = 0; i < params[0].length; i++) {
                System.out.format("%d: %s, %s, %s => ", i, params[i][0], params[i][1], params[i][2]);
                Predictor.main(params[i]);
            }
        }

        static class Predictor {

            // Simplistic example taking 3 values and returning the index of the largest.
            public static int predict(double[] atts) {
                double highestLikeli = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                int classIndex = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < atts.length; i++) {
                    if (atts[i] > highestLikeli) {
                        highestLikeli = atts[i];
                        classIndex = i;
                    }
                }
                return classIndex;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                if (args.length == 3) {
                    double[] atts = new double[args.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) {
                        atts[i] = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.println(Predictor.predict(atts));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Results

```
    0: 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 => 2
    1: 5.5, 3.3, 4.4 => 0
    2: 4.4, 5.5, 3.3 => 1
```